# How can I manually stop attempting to connect to offline nodes

Tags: monerod, offline-nodes

When I start my full node, there are multiple offline nodes that bitmonerod keeps attempting to connect to.

How can I manually stop bitmonerod from trying to connect to nodes that are no longer working? If I do nothing, exactly how long does it take before offline nodes are dropped by the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly the IPs of these nodes are stored in `p2pstate.bin` and therefore bitmonerod (the daemon) will try to keep connecting to them. This also answers your second question. There are two solutions two solve this issue. First, you can delete `p2pstate.bin`. Bear in mind to exit bitmonerod first before doing this. Second, you can manually ban these offline nodes with the `ban` command in bitmonerod. This command allows you to ban a certain IP for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic IP baning is still not present in Monero. Boolberry (and later AEON) adopted an [ip banning mechanism](https://github.com/iamsmooth/aeon/commit/b62d0f238d089de8b95bf89a679a9261107de102) for misbehaving nodes. Multiple offenses are required to get banned but some DoS type of attacks result in immediate ban.

Comment: MoneroMooo and smooth merged some of the AEON / Boolberry IP banning code upstream to Monero shortly after the testnet hardfork, which was a preparation of the March 2016 mainnet hardfork. [Source](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/commit/4cea2b13b221bed66023254dd3356f2548a08df4). Note that being offline isn't malicious behavior per se and therefore won't receive an automatic IP ban.

Comment: nice, missed that.